# Parsing XML in C# with XSD file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am parsing this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03 file:///C:/Users/s61205/Desktop/pain.002.001.03.xsd">
    <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>5609457</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2020-04-01T09:27:26</CreDtTm>
            <InitgPty>
                <Id>
                    <OrgId>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>ESSESESS</Id>
                            <SchmeNm>
                                <Cd>BANK</Cd>
                            </SchmeNm>
                        </Othr>
                        <Othr>
                            <Id>0033072166</Id>
                            <SchmeNm>
                                <Cd>CUST</Cd>
                            </SchmeNm>
                        </Othr>
                    </OrgId>
                </Id>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlMsgId>GB3UKBACS191122005</OrgnlMsgId>
            <OrgnlMsgNmId>pain.001.001.03</OrgnlMsgNmId>
            <OrgnlNbOfTxs>2</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
            <OrgnlCtrlSum>28218</OrgnlCtrlSum>
        </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
        <OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
            <OrgnlPmtInfId>15245 1</OrgnlPmtInfId>
            <OrgnlNbOfTxs>2</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
            <OrgnlCtrlSum>28218</OrgnlCtrlSum>
            <!--(if all correct,   if not -> PART  - see below example on pain.002 in that case) -->
            <PmtInfSts>ACSP</PmtInfSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>STOESI05202004010841583174000001</StsId>
                <OrgnlInstrId>645346300087</OrgnlInstrId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>15245 1 22</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <TxSts>ACSP</TxSts>
                <AcctSvcrRef>STOESI05202004010841583174000001</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="SEK">25116.00</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdExctnDt>2020-04-01</ReqdExctnDt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>Company</Nm>
                    </Cdtr>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
            <TxInfAndSts>
                <StsId>STOESI05202004010841583174000002</StsId>
                <OrgnlInstrId>645346300088</OrgnlInstrId>
                <OrgnlEndToEndId>15245 1 23</OrgnlEndToEndId>
                <TxSts>ACSP</TxSts>
                <AcctSvcrRef>STOESI05202004010841583174000002</AcctSvcrRef>
                <OrgnlTxRef>
                    <Amt>
                        <InstdAmt Ccy="SEK">3102.00</InstdAmt>
                    </Amt>
                    <ReqdExctnDt>2020-04-01</ReqdExctnDt>
                    <Cdtr>
                        <Nm>Company 2</Nm>
                    </Cdtr>
                </OrgnlTxRef>
            </TxInfAndSts>
        </OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
    </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

And I am using this XSD for it (just the problematic part):

```
<xs:complexType name="OriginalGroupInformation20">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="OrgnlMsgId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element name="OrgnlMsgNmId" type="Max35Text"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OrgnlCreDtTm" type="ISODateTime"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OrgnlNbOfTxs" type="Max15NumericText"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="OrgnlCtrlSum" type="DecimalNumber"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="GrpSts" type="TransactionGroupStatus3Code"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="StsRsnInf" type="StatusReasonInformation8"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="NbOfTxsPerSts" type="NumberOfTransactionsPerStatus3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And thru .NET xsd tool, I generate this C# class (again just the problem part of it):

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03")]
public partial class OriginalGroupInformation20 {
    
    private string orgnlMsgIdField;
    
    private string orgnlMsgNmIdField;
    
    private System.DateTime orgnlCreDtTmField;
    
    private bool orgnlCreDtTmFieldSpecified;
    
    private string orgnlNbOfTxsField;
    
    private decimal orgnlCtrlSumField;
    
    private bool orgnlCtrlSumFieldSpecified;
    
    private TransactionGroupStatus3Code grpStsField;
    
    private bool grpStsFieldSpecified;
    
    private StatusReasonInformation8[] stsRsnInfField;
    
    private NumberOfTransactionsPerStatus3[] nbOfTxsPerStsField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string OrgnlMsgId {
        get {
            return this.orgnlMsgIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlMsgIdField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string OrgnlMsgNmId {
        get {
            return this.orgnlMsgNmIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlMsgNmIdField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime OrgnlCreDtTm {
        get {
            return this.orgnlCreDtTmField;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlCreDtTmField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool OrgnlCreDtTmSpecified {
        get {
            return this.orgnlCreDtTmFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlCreDtTmFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public string OrgnlNbOfTxs {
        get {
            return this.orgnlNbOfTxsField;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlNbOfTxsField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal OrgnlCtrlSum {
        get {
            return this.orgnlCtrlSumField;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlCtrlSumField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool OrgnlCtrlSumSpecified {
        get {
            return this.orgnlCtrlSumFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.orgnlCtrlSumFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public TransactionGroupStatus3Code GrpSts {
        get {
            return this.grpStsField;
        }
        set {
            this.grpStsField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool GrpStsSpecified {
        get {
            return this.grpStsFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.grpStsFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("StsRsnInf")]
    public StatusReasonInformation8[] StsRsnInf {
        get {
            return this.stsRsnInfField;
        }
        set {
            this.stsRsnInfField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NbOfTxsPerSts")]
    public NumberOfTransactionsPerStatus3[] NbOfTxsPerSts {
        get {
            return this.nbOfTxsPerStsField;
        }
        set {
            this.nbOfTxsPerStsField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03")]
public enum TransactionGroupStatus3Code {
    
    /// <remarks/>
    ACTC,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    RCVD,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    PART,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    RJCT,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    PDNG,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    ACCP,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    ACSP,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    ACSC,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    ACWC,
}
```

But even if I dont have this tag in my XML:

```
<CstmrPmtStsRpt><OrgnlGrpInfAndSts><GrpSts>
```

It's filled with first value from enum in C# class: "ACTC". Please why is this value filled?

Comment: An enum in c# is an integer and defaults to zero as the default value.  An enum by default assigns values in sequence 0,1,2,3,4.  So ACTC is equal to zero and that is why the values is filled in.

Comment: As @jdweng stated, because it's the 1st item in your enum. Just add a value of `None` or `NotSet` (or something similar) as the first item in your enum. (ex: NotSet, ACTC, RCVD, ...)